# Cannot display Ovrvision image on Unity application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I am Using Unity 5.4.0f3 Personal(32bit), I developed demonstration application to display camera picture and three-dimensional AR which I acquired in Ovrvision Pro on Oculus Rift.
So I place prefabs, OVRCameraRig (view point camera) and OvrvisionSDK (Ovrvision imaging) from package `ovrvision_unity5_includeOVR.unitypackage`, and locate moving  3D objects. I intend an application that the 3D objects are moving in front of the video captured at Ovrvision.
[Placing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLLOW.jpg)
However, Ovrvision seems not to be recognized. The inspector of OvrvisionSDK says `"Ovrvision status closed"`. And pressing [Play] button, `"Ovrvision Open Error"` occurs.
[Ovrvision Open Error on Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMlwx.jpg)
And when I connect Oculus Rift into the PC, the Unity editor crashes.

The version of Unity editor is 5.4.0f3, and the firmware version of Ovrvision Pro is 1.1, the latest.
I started developing with Unity only one and half month ago, and I may misunderstand the role of various packages and prefabs of Unity.

Best regards,
ichihara456

Comment: Thats not a programming question! You are wrong here at stackoverflow for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the solution to your problem, but I had similar issues with ovrvision (not using Unity, though). Turns out that in my case one USB port I was using was not a USB3 port (needs to be blue). 
Might be worth a try...
Good luck!